# why am getting Nullpointer Exception?

Tags: android

am trying to read a text file but getting exception at openRawResource ,i had my text file inside drawable folder, here is my code.

```
public void PlayWithRawFiles() throws IOException {      
    String str="";
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();          
    InputStream is = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.dict_7letter);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    if (is!=null) {                         
        while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
            buf.append(str + "\n" );
        }               
    }       
    is.close(); 
    Log.d("from dict", "........."+buf);                


}
```

Comment: May be your context is null.... else show your logcat output.

Comment: yes i know bt how to get that context then

Comment: Drawable folder is for drawables not text files. You should use assets folder for random files you want to include.

Comment: why are you writing openRawResource(R.drawable.dict_7letter)? ?It should be R.raw.dict_7letter

Comment: Why do you put your text inside a drawable folder and wondering why it is not working? Put it in Assets and search for a tutorial how to read text file from assets

Comment: i have tested this code in an individual project there it is working fine.

Comment: @SilentKiller  i have to pass context of my current activity or of my base activity ?

Comment: @Jitendra current activity.

Comment: @SiletKiller i did that but same problem

Answer (score 0):

Put your text file in assets and write following code to read text file:

```
    public String ReadFromfile(String fileName, Context context) {
        StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
        InputStream fIn = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        BufferedReader input = null;
        try {
            fIn = context.getResources().getAssets()
                    .open(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
            input = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = "";
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                returnString.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (isr != null)
                    isr.close();
                if (fIn != null)
                    fIn.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.getMessage();
            }
        }
        return returnString.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place your text file inside raw folder under resources.
then access it as

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dict_7letter);
```

If you needs to keep it in drawable folder itself access it using

```
getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/dict_7letter","drawable", getPackageName())

InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/dict_7letter","drawable", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: i tried both but not working still giving me Null Pointer Exception

Comment: can u debug and check which object is null, so we can identify what exactly is causing this null pointer exception

Comment: getResources()  is giving null Pointer

Comment: Where have you written the above method? Activity or any other class?